# Calculadora em PHP, me ajudem a solucionar pfv

Tags: php

Olá preciso muito de alguma ajuda, pois estou com dificuldades.

No final não aparece o resultado da operação feita e também se alguém puder comentar algumas linha para que eu possa entender melhor... desde já agradeço quem puder me ajudar

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculadora PHP</title>
<style type = "text/css">
.style1 {font-family: algerian; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #CC0066; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="500" height="100" align="center" bgcolor="#F6CEEC" border="3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#CC0066">
<tr>
<td><form name="calculadora" method="post" action="">
<div align="center"><span class="style1">Calculadora </span> <br></div>
Valor 1: <input name="valor1" type="number"  value="<? echo $valor1 ?>"/></br>
Valor 2: <input name="valor2" type="number" value="<? echo $valor2 ?>"/> <br />
Selecione uma operação: <select name="sinal" size="1" ><option value=""></option>
<option value="+">Adição</option>
<option value="-">Subtração</option>
<option value="*">Multiplicação</option>
<option value="/">Divisão</option> 
  <br/><br/>
<input name="Calcular" type="submit" value="Calcular"> <br />
<input name="Limpar" type="reset" value="Limpar"> <br /><br />
</select> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<?php
   $valor1= $_POST['valor1'];
   $valor2= $_POST['valor2'];
   $sinal = $_POST['sinal'];
   switch ($sinal)
   {
  case 'Adição': $total = $valor1 +  $valor2;   break;
  case 'Subtração': $total = $valor1 -  $valor2;    break;
  case 'Multiplicação': $total = $valor1 *  $valor2;    break;
  case 'Divisão': $total = $valor1 /  $valor2;  break;
      echo "O resultado da operação é:" .$total; 

   }
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No `case` você está usando o `texto dos options` enquanto `$_POST['sinal'];` te retorna o sinal da operação, ou seja o `value` do option!
2. O echo deverá ficar fora do `switch`

Select

```
Selecione uma operação: <select name="sinal" size="1" >
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Adição">Adição</option>
<option value="Subtração">Subtração</option>
<option value="Multiplicação">Multiplicação</option>
<option value="Divisão">Divisão</option>
```

PHP

```
$valor1= $_POST['valor1'];
$valor2= $_POST['valor2'];
$sinal = $_POST['sinal'];
switch ($sinal)
{
  case 'Adição': $total = $valor1 +  $valor2;   break;
  case 'Subtração': $total = $valor1 -  $valor2;    break;
  case 'Multiplicação': $total = $valor1 *  $valor2;    break;
  case 'Divisão': $total = $valor1 /  $valor2;  break; 
}

//fora do switch
echo "O resultado da operação é:" .$total;
```

> Pode deixar os `values do options` com os sinais das operações, porém nos `case do switch` tem que ser com os sinais.

Exemplo:

Se

```
<option value="+">Adição</option>
```

então

```
case '+': $total = $valor1 +  $valor2;   break;
```